# Issues with Converting Types in C# / Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project that has a canvas with four UI Button objects. When I load the canvas, I want the script to check each Button and see if there is a corresponding image file saved in the local drive and then, if so, display that image on the Button - this is achieved with GetPictureandShowIt(), which works for a single button.

The issue I'm having is when trying to cycle through each of the different buttons. The below script successfully cycles through the button names properly (which have all been set with the necessary tag), but I can't set the button variable with the appropriate name using: **button = getCount[ButtonNumber];** and therefore the GetPictureandShowIt() method can't apply the image to the next button. I get an error of *Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to ' UnityEngine.UI.Button'*.

I'm still relatively new at Unity/C#, so apologies if it is a straightforward answer.

```
public class LoadImages : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public Button button;
    public FloatVariable FrameNumber;
    public StringVariable GalleryName;
        
    int ButtonNumber = 0;
    int ButtonMax;
    private GameObject[] getCount;

    void Start()
    {        
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Frame");
        ButtonMax = getCount.Length;         
        
        while (ButtonNumber <= ButtonMax)
        {
            button = getCount[ButtonNumber];
            GetPictureAndShowIt();
            Debug.Log("Frame#: " + getCount[ButtonNumber]);
            FrameNumber.value++;
            ButtonNumber++;
        }
   }
...
```

Comment: If `Button` is a `GameObject` then you can cast with `button = (Button)getCount[ButtonNumber];`. Or declare the array as `private Button[] getCount;` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Frame");` you are getting a `GameObject` not a `Button` type. Check the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

Maybe you need to:
`button = getCount[ButtonNumber].GetComponent<Button>();` if the button component is in that gameobject.